Index lua table with table
if I have an x and y I want the following to print 6(without making a string or combining the numbers into one):
a = {}
a[{1, 2}] = 6
print(a[{1, 2}]) -- nil

unfortunately lua uses the address of the table as keys instead of the value and since the two {1, 2} tables have different addresses it prints nil
I've looked at the lua book, reddit and stack overflow without success.
The following also doesn't work, because it only takes the first value of the unpacked table as the key:
a = {}
a[table.unpack({1, 2})] = 6
print(a[table.unpack({1, 2})]) -- 6
print(a[1]) -- 6

Is there a nice way to do this(again without making a string or combining the numbers)?

Is nested tables okay for you? Then you could do a[1][2] = 6

@shingo I didn't come across that one when I was googling. It answers my question. I'll see if I can mark mine as a duplicate.
